# Function in other function which add extra mysql query

Tags: php

This is a class of how I imagine to add extra query condition, but it's not working. My question is if this can be done, and if yes - How ?

```
class query
{
function add($y)
{
if($y) { return 'y'; }
}
function query()
{
$query->select('*');
$query->from('table');
$add = $this->add($y);
if($add) { $query->where('smt = smt'); }
}
}
```

Call class:

```
$items = new Query;
$items->add('y');
$items->query();
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly is not working and preferrably provide exact script output. PS. Your class methods are missing visibility declarations, you should read about those [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: Extra query is not invoked, then I use this function `$items->add('y');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ...

```
class query {
private $y = null;

function $add($y=null) {
if($y!=null)
$this->y = $y;

return $this->y;
}

function query()
{
$query->select('*');
$query->from('table');
$add = $this->add();
if($add) { $query->where('smt = smt'); }
}
}
```

Call class :

```
$items = new Query;
$items->add('y');
$items->query();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method Query::query() contains this line of code:

`$add = $this->add($y);`

But $y is not defined, so your `if` check in the Query::add() method does not return anything. As such, $add is `null` and so the last `$query->where()` is not called.

If you need to preserve values across various instance method calls, store the values on an instance variable or pass them around as method parameters.